# Why was my question regarding creating an Archlinux AMI closed as not constructive?

Tags: support, closed-questions

[Creating an ArchLinux AMI](https://serverfault.com/questions/354426/creating-an-archlinux-ami)

I would like to know why my question isn't constructive, is it the way I worded my question? Did I forget details I should have added? Or is it something else I did wrong? Thank you for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the looks of it, the question there was either, "How do I build an Arch Linux AMI from scratch," or, "where can I find an Arch Linux AMI?". The former is far too complicated for a single answer since there are a lot of variable we don't have. The later is a product recommendation question which we don't do.

Building an AMI of anything is a lot like building a server from scratch, just with a nice Amazon flavor to it. Such images are highly customized, which makes it hard for us to really help you.

An alternate question may be:

> What is the base process for building an Arch AMI? Once I know to make one at all, I can customize the packages I need; I just need the first few steps.

Comment: Sprinkling the words "technical requirements" and "official specification" in that sort of alternate question would likely help it sound Professional too.